# Why do we use conjugate transpose IFFT in OFDM

Tags: digital-communications, digital-to-analog

I have a question regarding the OFDM and using the conjugate transpose of vector (matrix).

As you know, if we have a block of data,let's call it $X_n$, consisting of $N$ data symbols, we should apply for IDFT for that block, and let's say that we get $Y_n$ which is $Y_n = \text{IDFT}(X_n)$.

After that step, the conjugate transpose for the IDFT must be taken.  So what's the benefit from taking that? If you have documents which explains that in simple way, it will be appreciated.

Comment: nothing in OFDM says that you need to take the conjugate transpose. That seems to be something specific to whatever literature you're reading at this point (and we don't know what you're reading).

Comment: @MarcusMüller  thank you for your quick comment, In reality, I've read a paper saying: Let s be the  data block consisting of N data symbols with  variance σ^2 . Applying  IDFT  to  each  block,  we  get x=FH(s) where F is  the N-point  DFT  matrix  and  the superscript H
represents  the  conjugate  transpose  of  vector (matrix).  ... do you mean that sentence means something else ? could you please explain it again?

Comment: that statement has nothing to do with the question you're asking – the conjugate complex of the DFT Matrix is simply the IDFT matrix. You're transposing the DFT matrix, not the result.

Comment: @MarcusMüller   OK, so what is the benefit of transposing the DFT matrix ? why should we transpose it?

Comment: Read my comment – conjugate transposed DFT matrix is the IDFT matrix, and you want the IDFT.